# Guard: how to run specific tags from w/in Guard's console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, spork

I'm using Spork and Guard in my RSpec test suite. I'm excluding slow tests from running with:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.filter_run_excluding slow: true
  ...
end
```

Then when I need to I run the slow tests in a separate shell with: $ `rspec . --tag slow`

I'm wondering if there's a shortcut to run the slow tags in *same* shell that Guard is auto-running its tests in?

There's a console `>` prompt?  And after looking at documentation I find that typing >`. rspec . --tag slow` works...but that's just a little more verbose than switching to another shell. Seems like this would be a fairly common request. Ideas?

Answer (score 6):

You can define groups and have different rspec configurations in each group.

Append the code below to the contents of `/Guardfile`:

```
scope group: :fast

group :fast do
  guard 'rspec', cli: '--tag ~slow' do
    # code for watching
  end
end

group :slow do
  guard 'rspec', cli: '--tag slow' do
    # code for watching
  end
end
```

When you start Guard, it defaults to the fast specs:

```
$ guard                                                                                                          
21:56:35 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running
21:56:35 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/Users/michi/testproject'
[1] {Fast} guard(main)>
```

Pressing enter will run all fast specs:

```
22:02:00 - INFO - Run Fast
22:02:00 - INFO - Running all specs
Run options: exclude {:slow=>true}
```

Now you can run just all the slow ones by pressing `slow`:

```
[2] {Fast} guard(main)> slow
22:02:50 - INFO - Run Slow
22:02:50 - INFO - Running all specs
Run options: include {:slow=>true}
```

You can also switch the scope to the slow specs and run them all by pressing enter:

```
[3] {Fast} guard(main)> scope slow
[4] {Slow} guard(main)>
22:03:30 - INFO - Run Slow
22:03:30 - INFO - Running all specs
Run options: include {:slow=>true}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: if this works, haven't had a chance to implement yet, then it's exactly what I'm looking for! thx!

Comment: Of course does it work, the above examples are copies from a real example from the shell :-)

Answer (score 1):

This code will run all the test that are tagged "fast" inside the files we are watching.

```
guard 'rspec', :version => 2, :cli => "--tag ~fast" do
# code for watching
end
```

You need to use cli option to run only the tests you need.

Comment: so what's the command line trigger to run those tests (the ones tagged `fast` in your example)?

Comment: "--tag fast" means run only fast tests. "--tag ~fast" means run tests that are NOT fast.